# Xcode gives .DS_Store conflict error

Tags: xcode, error, git

Me and my partner are using Xcode's built-in git to edit code together. 
When I tried to pull a change, I am having .DS_Store files conflict.

We are both working on the storyboard and adding images to the project. 
Could it be because of the images we are adding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .DS_Store changes when you alter the directory's view options: align, sort order, view mode... You don't need version control on it. To ignore the changes add `.DS_Store` in the `.gitignore` or the global one in `~/.config/git/ignore`.

Comment: That is an odd place for the global one run `git config --get core` to see where your global file is

Comment: In MacOS Catalina, try `git config --list --show-origin`